# How to set a parameter persistently by a query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, parameters, persist

With `SESSION` and `LOCAL` below, I cannot set a parameter persistently in **PostgreSQL**:

```sql
SET SESSION log_statement = 'all'
```

```sql
SET LOCAL log_statement = 'all'
```

Actually with `PERSIST` and `GLOBAL` below in **MySQL**,  I can set a parameter persistently and semi-persistently respectively:

```sql
SET PERSIST transaction_isolation = 'READ-UNCOMMITTED';
```

```sql
SET GLOBAL transaction_isolation = 'READ-COMMITTED';
```

So, are there any ways to set a parameter persistently by a query in **PostgreSQL**?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ALTER SYSTEM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html) if you want to change it globally for all databases and users. Or change it in [postgresql.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html).
Note that you need to reload the configuration if you do that (depending on the parameter you might even need to restart Postgres completely - this is documented for each property)

If you only want to change it for a specific database, use [ALTER DATABASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html)

If you only want to change it for a user, use [ALTER USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html)